# Is there a way to install programmatically the text to speech English UK Male language in android studio

Tags: android, mobile, mobile-application, google-text-to-speech

Is there a way to select the male voice in English UK? I already have a code on how to install the English UK but it installs the first option which is Female. Hope you can help me. Thank you.

Here is the code for anyone who's asking:

```
@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        float srate = sharedPreferences.getFloat("srate", FDEFAULT);
        String svoice = sharedPreferences.getString("svoice", "HMMM");
        Locale loc = null;

        if (svoice.equals("")) {
            loc = SDEFAULT;
        } else if(svoice.equals("UK Male")) {
            loc = Locale.UK;
        } else if(svoice.equals("US Female")) {
            loc = Locale.US;
        }

        int result = toSpeech.setLanguage(loc);
```

Comment: you need to call `toSpeech.setVoice()` using the new API. Query the list of available voices first.

Comment: Hello @brandall, I'm new with android, how can I query the list of available voices? Sorry for the late reply because I'm busy with my school works